# Are std::streams already movable?

Tags: c++, gcc, stream, c++11, rvalue

GNU gcc 4.3 partially supports the upcoming c++0x standard: among the implemented features the rvalue reference. By means of the rvalue reference it should be possible to move a non-copyable object or return it from a function.

Are std::streams already movable **by means of rvalue reference** or does the current library implementation lack something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current g++ svn, rvalue reference support has not yet been added to streams. I suspect adding it will not be too difficult and as ever with open source software, patches are, I'm sure, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

After a quick investigation it comes out that the **rvalue reference** support has not been added yet to streams.

To return a non-copyable object from a function indeed it is sufficient to implement the *move constructor* as follows:

```
struct noncopyable
{
    noncopyable()
    {}

    // move constructor
    noncopyable(noncopyable &&)
    {}

private:
    noncopyable(const noncopyable &);
    noncopyable &operator=(const noncopyable &);
};
```

Such constructor is supposed to transfer the ownership to the new object leaving the one being passed in a default state.

That said, it is possible to return an object from a function in this way:

```
noncopyable factory()
{
    noncopyable abc;
    return std::move(abc);
}
```

While std::stream does not support move constructors it seems that STL containers shipped with gcc 4.3.2 do already support it.